# Neural network prediction in Keras returning the same value for different inputs

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, prediction

I am trying to predict an array of values with a Keras neural network, as follows:

```
def create_network():
    np.random.seed(0)
    number_of_features = (22) 
    # start neural network
    network = models.Sequential()  
    # Adding three layers
    # Add fully connected layer with ReLU
    network.add(layers.Dense(units=35, activation="relu", input_shape=(number_of_features,)))
    # Add fully connected layer with ReLU 
    network.add(layers.Dense(units=35, activation='relu'))
    # Add fully connected layer with no activation function
    network.add(layers.Dense(units=1))
    # Compile neural network
    network.compile(loss='mse',  
                    optimizer='RMSprop',  
                    metrics=['mse'])  
    # Return compiled network
    return network


neural_network = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_network, epochs = 10, batch_size = 100, verbose = 0)

neural_network.fit(x_train, y_train)

neural_network.predict(x_test)
```

When using the code to make a prediction I get the following output data:

```
array([[-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031],
       [-0.23991031]])
```

The different values in this array should not be the same, since the input data points are not the same. Why is this happening?

The data is split into train and test like this:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df3, df2['RETURN NEXT 12 MONTHS'], test_size=0.2)# 0.2 means 20% of the values are used for testing
```

Here are some samples of the data:

```
x_train
     RETURN ON INVESTED CAPITAL  ...  VOLATILITY
226                      0.0436  ...      0.3676
309                      0.1073  ...      0.3552
306                      0.1073  ...      0.3660
238                      0.1257  ...      0.4352
254                      0.1960  ...      0.4230
308                      0.1073  ...      0.3661
327                      0.2108  ...      0.2674
325                      0.2108  ...      0.2836
...
```

The dataframe above has 22 columns, and about 100 rows.

The corresponding y training data is:

```
y_train
226    0.137662
309    1.100000
306    0.725738
238    0.244292
254   -0.557806
308    1.052402
327   -0.035730
...
```

I have tried to use different number of epochs, batch_size, and different model architecture, but they all give the same output for all input.

Per epoch loss:

```
Epoch 1/10
 10/100 [==>...........................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 1525.8176 - mse: 1525.8176
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 13771.8389 - mse: 13771.8389
Epoch 2/10
 10/100 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4315.0015 - mse: 4315.0015
 30/100 [========>.....................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 23554.2446 - mse: 23554.2441
 40/100 [===========>..................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 18089.7297 - mse: 18089.7305
 50/100 [==============>...............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 15002.7878 - mse: 15002.7871
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 10520.1019 - mse: 10520.1025
Epoch 3/10
 10/100 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2722.1135 - mse: 2722.1135
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 167us/step - loss: 8500.4698 - mse: 8500.4697
Epoch 4/10
 10/100 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 3192.2231 - mse: 3192.2231
 50/100 [==============>...............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4860.0622 - mse: 4860.0620
 90/100 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7377.6898 - mse: 7377.6904
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 6911.2499 - mse: 6911.2500
Epoch 5/10
 10/100 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1996.5687 - mse: 1996.5687
 60/100 [=================>............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 6902.6661 - mse: 6902.6660
 70/100 [====================>.........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 6162.6467 - mse: 6162.6470
 90/100 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 6195.4129 - mse: 6195.4131
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 5773.2919 - mse: 5773.2925
Epoch 6/10
 10/100 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 3063.1946 - mse: 3063.1946
 80/100 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5351.2784 - mse: 5351.2793
 90/100 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5100.9203 - mse: 5100.9214
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 4755.7785 - mse: 4755.7793
Epoch 7/10
 10/100 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 3710.8032 - mse: 3710.8032
 70/100 [====================>.........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4607.9606 - mse: 4607.9609
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 943us/step - loss: 3847.0730 - mse: 3847.0732
Epoch 8/10
 10/100 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1742.0632 - mse: 1742.0632
 30/100 [========>.....................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2304.5816 - mse: 2304.5818
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 3109.5293 - mse: 3109.5293
Epoch 9/10
 10/100 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2027.7537 - mse: 2027.7537
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 574us/step - loss: 2537.4794 - mse: 2537.4795
Epoch 10/10
 10/100 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2966.5125 - mse: 2966.5125
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 177us/step - loss: 2191.3686 - mse: 2191.3687
```

Comment: This means that your specific model is simply not able to learn anything useful given your data and the number of epochs. Experiment with different model architectures, optimization algorithms, and no. of epochs

Comment: @Sindre Fjellavli Your network is unable to learn a mapping between x and y spaces. Can you share your per-epoch loss? Also, what is your method of creating the test dataset?

Comment: It would be better if you could post samples of your input data